# load images from Supabase for flutterapp

Tags: flutter, supabase

how  load list of images in supabase for flutter app?

how  load list of images in Supabase for flutter app

I need to load the photos that I have saved in Supabase. None of the methods I have used have led to the correct loading of the photos. please guide me

Answer (score -1):

**Query Images from Supabase:**
Use Supabase's storage.from('bucket').download('path') method to download an image. Here's an example:

```dart
Future<void> fetchImage() async {
  final response = await supabase
      .storage
      .from('bucket_name') // Replace with your bucket name
      .download('path_to_your_image.jpg'); // Replace with the path to your image
  if (response.error != null) {
    print('Error fetching image: ${response.error!.message}');
  } else {
    // Use response.data to access the image data
    final imageBytes = response.data;
    // Use the imageBytes to display or process the image
  }
}
```

**Display the Image:**
You can use the retrieved image bytes to display the image in your Flutter app. For example, you can use the Image.memory widget:

```dart
Image.memory(
  imageBytes,
  fit: BoxFit.cover, // or any other BoxFit option
)
```

I hope this helps you!